# cut -d not working in case of rpm -qa kernel

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to extract the latest kernel version using

`rpm -qa kernel| sort -V| rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev`

However I get all the kernel versions as the output and not just the latest one.

This works on a string, e.g.

`echo "a b"| rev | cut -d ' ' -f1`

returns `b`.

What am I doing wrong in the first case

Comment: `rpm -q --qf '%{version}-%{release}\n' kernel | sort | tail -1` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the output of `rpm -qa kernel`, it does not contain any space so `cut -d' ' -f1` is a no-op here.

Here is why i get on my system:

```
% rpm -qa kernel
kernel-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64
```

So to get the latest one, after `sort -V` use `head -1` to get the first line:

```
% rpm -qa kernel | sort -V | head -1
kernel-2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: How can I get the last line which would be the latest kernel if I don't know how many kernels exist?

Comment: @user2851669 Check my answer: `rpm -qa kernel | sort -V | head -1`

Comment: It sorts the kernel versions in ascending order not descending

Comment: I get the following output -  "rpm -qa kernel | sort -V" returns
kernel-3.14.35-28.38.x86_64
kernel-4.4.19-29.55.x86_64
kernel-4.4.30-32.54.x86_64

Comment: tail -1 solves the problem. Not sure why I didn't think of this before!

Comment: @user2851669 Note that: after the output of `rpm -qa kernel | sort -V`, the first one is the latest kernel (`head -1`) whereas `tail -1` would get you the oldest one.

Comment: The output I am getting is sorted in ascending order.